# Generating a polynomial function from time complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I'm doing exam review for an exam i have in a few days and i've come across this question.
"Count the number of assignments in the following code (include all loop counter initializations and increments). now record your working in plain text on the exam page. give your answer as a polynomial function of n (do not simplify using O, Theta, or Omega notation).

```
for(i = 0; i < n; ++i){

    for(j = 0; j<i+1; ++j){

               sum +=a[j];

   }
}
```

To my knowledge this is O(n^2) as it is nested loops (I'm aware this is wrong as the question states not to use O notations).  All the examples on this topic i've come across all simplify to O notation.

Is the answer just as simple as

n^2 + n?

as `sum +=a[j]` is executed n times and `for(j = 0; j<i+1; ++j{` is also executed n*n times

Comment: No, it's not that simple of an answer. I'm not sure how you've come to your answer. I'd suggest counting out the first few iterations of this to see the sequence. An important formula you'll need is `1+2+...+n = (n*n+n)/2`.

Comment: This is not a question about complexity, it's a question of counting assignments. For example in the single line `for(i=0; i<n; i++)` there's an initial assignment to `i`, and `i++` gets executed `n` times in total during the lifetime of the code, so there's a contribution of `n+1` assignments from this one line of code. You have to do the other lines similarly (although they're more difficult).

Comment: A second hint is that for the inner loop, you have to count the assignments for each value of `i`, and them sum them up. For example, in `for(j=0; j<i+1; ++j)`, the assignment `j=0` is performed 1 time per value of `i`, and the increment `++j` is performed `i+1` times. You then need to sum these over the range of `i`.

Comment: The hint from @Elliott is helpful, because when you sum up some of the terms as I've suggested, you'll need that formula (and it's a good one to know, because it comes up a lot in computer science).

Comment: as a finishing product do you need to do induction on it? making it (k^2 + 3k + 2)/2 and thats the polynomial?

Comment: @Jimbo, there's no need at all for anything fancy like induction proofs here. And that formula can't be the answer, as it doesn't result in whole numbers (if `k=2` the poly is 4.5).

Comment: I think you may need to review some of the basics here, because I'm not sure how you could think that `sum +=a[j]` is executed `n` times when it's part of the inner loop.

Comment: Yeah you're 100% right, it seems that im lacking a few things, do you know any good resources? @Elliott

Comment: @Jimbo, well problems like this have two prerequisites: You know the basics of how to code (assignments, prints/input, arrays, loops, if statements) and have used them enough to be confident with them; the second assumption is that you can use a bit of maths to figure out the sequence and finally work out the sum. From what you've said it seems you haven't quite done enough coding to get comfortable with how loops work, so I'd suggest solving more problems like those on HackerRank.

Comment: [cont.] A common beginner mistake is to be academic about coding - but it's more of a "doing" subject, where you'll think about a problem, scribble some pictures on a paper, and solve it in any way that makes sense. You'll naturally get better at it this way, you'll understand what you're doing, and more than that it'll actually be enjoyable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i   j   sum     notes
0   0   +=a[0]
0   1   -       break the inner loop
1   0   +=a[0]
1   1   +=a[1]
1   2   -       break the inner loop
2   0   +=a[0]
2   1   +=a[1]
2   2   +=a[2]
2   3   -       break the inner loop
... ...
n-1 n-1 +=a[n-1]
n-1 n   -       break the inner loop
n   -   -       break the outer loop
```

- You have `n` assignments (from 0 to n-1) of variable `i` plus the last one (the one that breaks the outer loop), for a total of `n+1`.
- For each outer loop, you have `i+1` assignments of variable `j` plus the last one (the one that breaks the inner loop), for a total of `2+3+4+...+(n+1) = (n+1)(n+2)/2-1`.
- For each outer loop, you have `i+1` assignments of variable `sum`, for a total of `1+2+3+...+n = n(n+1)/2`.

The total number of assignments is `n+1 + (n+1)(n+2)/2-1 + n(n+1)/2`, i.e. `n^2 + 3n + 1`.

Comment: I agree with the answer, but are we possibly over-explaining a homework question?

Comment: Ohhhhh i get tyvm :D there's a few things i'm going to have to brush up on do you know any resources / what to google to get similar questions to this?